# Medieval fantasy book: flat worlds, golden skins, eternal night and days

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I am looking for a fantasy (medieval) book, for teenagers/young adults.

Here is what I remember:

- In a world split in constant night and day part
- Nobody goes to the night part
- There are 'normal people' and 'golden' (or 'amber' or 'of the sun') people
- A guy, with a golden girl have to go in the night part (why? I do not remember!)
- They end up climbing a giant wall of plants, ending on another flat world (might be tilted) on top of the first one
- The flat worlds on top of each other explains the constant night and day

I do not remember the end well:

- They are able to fly in space, going down, following the pillars of the world, that end up on a final larger world... end

Details:

- I read it in French around 2010
- I think the author was relatively young

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall any character or place names?  Any details of the cover art?  You can [edit] in any additional details you remember.

Comment: Unfortunatly I do not remember any names